# Mail Server Handling with Node.js

Tags: email, smtp, mail-server

I'm creating a service that requires users being able to email `anyone@mysite.com` where mysite is my.. site.

Should I go through the trouble of setting up my email server or is there a hosted email provider that I can use and constantly poll?

Thanks.

Comment: You could also look at system that push the email to your node app. Such as CloudMailin.com

Comment: Are there other services like CloudMailin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's personal choice. You will need to set the DNS MX records accordingly, whichever option you go for. Your own server is best (certainly for incoming mail), but it does take more effort.

Most ISPs will receive email for you (provided you're giving them some of your cash), but it has its limitations. For example, to get messages from your ISP, you will either need to use POP3, which you could use either to retrieve messages into your mail client, or into your own mail server for subsequent processing; or your ISP may support IMAP4, which means the messages are stored on their server.
Either way, it has limitations. For instance, you will only see the message headers/body, rather than the SMTP envelope, so you won't be able to do as much in the way of message processing. A major piece of data that only appears in the SMTP envelope is the "Bcc" address (for good reason).
Also bouncebacks cannot be reliably issued at this stage - the message headers are not always reliable - especially when a spammer has used fake addresses in message headers.

It is unlikely that an ISP is going to allow anywhere near the level of configuration you would enjoy with a decent mail server and running extra mailboxes might prove expensive.

If you go down the route of receiving mail directly to your own mail server, you will need to configure your firewall/router to allow access on Port 25 for incoming SMTP. You will also need either a static IP address, or help from a "dynanic DNS" service.

You should be aware that (particularly when you start out) you will have no reputation, so it is likely that some recipient mail servers will refuse your mails (they might think you're a spammer). That may be a permanent problem with a minority of mail servers, but most should begin to trust you once you've spent long enough sending legitimate emails.

It is vital that you set up your mail server so that it cannot be used as an open relay.